# Kubernetes: Nginx Ingress not providing external IP address

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to create an Ingress for my Kubernetes cluster on Google Compute Engine. It was working fine while I was using the `gke` controller class. But I had to change it to `nginx` controller to be able to specify the back end timeout. The problem is that my Ingress is not being provided with an external IP address.

## This is my Ingress manifest:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-router
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "1200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-fail-timeout: "1200"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-ip
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: nginxsecret
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 8000
      - path: /cron/*
        backend:
          serviceName: esg
          servicePort: 8000

      - path: /task/*
        backend:
          serviceName: esg
          servicePort: 8000

      - path: /api/connections/update/*
        backend:
          serviceName: esg
          servicePort: 8000

      - path: /api/drive/scansheet/*
        backend:
          serviceName: esg
          servicePort: 8000
```

Is there any configuration missing?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. It was due to the fact I had not configured the Nginx controller for the Ingress.